Access AWS RDS from Both LAMBDA and Locally
I created an AWS RDS Postgres instance and allowed public access. Initially, I successfully connected to it locally. Next, I set up a Lambda function and connected it to the RDS. I created an Internet Gateway and a NAT to provide internet access to the Lambda function. After testing, the Lambda function worked as expected, connecting to the database and accessing the internet. However, now I'm unable to access the RDS from my local machine. How can I troubleshoot this issue?
I have 3 private subnet, 1 public subnet. Security groups of Lambda and RDS allow traffic from all port publicly.
I tried creating RDS proxy but still not able to access RDS from local.




When you say "unable to access", what happens? Does it return an error message, or does it take several seconds before failing? Adding a NAT Gateway would not have impacted that access. It is more likely to be the Security Group on the RDS database. Can you show us how you configured the Inbound rules on the Security Group?

Also, is there a specific reason why you wanted to grant Internet access for the Lambda function?

@JohnRotenstein Lambda is consuming public api, thats why it needs internet access.
There is one VPC Security Group attached to my rds allows all traffic from all ipv4 and ipv6, inbonud as well as outbound
IPv4 All traffic All All 0.0.0.0/0
IPv6 All traffic All All ::/0

@JohnRotenstein I updated description with screenshots

Which subnet is the RDS instance in? I think RDS requires at least 2 subnets, and you only have 1 public subnet. For RDS to be publicly accessible, it has to be in public subnets. It sounds like it was working before, and then you converted the subnets RDS was using from public to private or something like that, when you added the NAT Gateway.

Very true! The RDS screen is showing that the subnet group has four subnets and is currently deployed in ap-southeast-2c. You should confirm that all those subnets are public subnets (particularly those in ap-southeast-2c).

Frankly, if you're going to open the RDS database to the entire world (which is not good for security), you could actually remove the Lambda function from the VPC and have it communicate with the database from the Internet. That would also save you the extra expense of having a NAT Gateway. However, I should point out that having a database accessible to the entire Internet is a bad idea for security.

Thanks, I created public subnet for each availability zone and it worked!!!!
I opened all the ports publicly to test the connection, I'll be restricting RDS access to limited IPs.
@JohnRotenstein RDS doesn't allow connection from Lambda without VPC over an internet, that's reason I ended up creating NAT and Internet Gateway.

I made a mistake of creating public subnet in only one availability zone. Solution is to create a public subnet in all availability zone.
